# jScrollPane jquery plugin, jspDrag doesn't exceed to end

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, jscrollpane

After some time fiddling today I mocked up a quick modular slider for one of my client's website. I wanted to theme the scrollbars so went ahead and picked up the the jQuery plugin called "jScrollPane" available here: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/. This simply did the trick and I was able to style the scrollbar with pictures. The only problem I am stumbling upon is that the scroll bar doesn't drag further than the middle, it does scroll horizontally the modules. Here is a quick jsFiddle to describe on my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/95fG6/. I am pretty sure that this is easily solvable and that I just have to set a parameter in the .js to make it work. But I am quick unfamiliar with the plugin therefore have no idea how to continue.

Thank you very much everyone! Thanks for taking your time!

Shad

Comment: BTW, the red and green thing is supposed to be the scrollbar, I just replaced with colors instead of the images. :)

Answer (score 0):

better you resize the width on red color

```
.jspDrag {
    background: red no-repeat;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 21px !important;
    width: 400px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

I hope this may be helpful to you
[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95fG6/16/)